# Unable to build Solution

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, namespaces, .net-framework-version

I run the Accord.NET.sln and the codes appears in the Visual Studio 2013.
I tried to build the solution and got the following errors.

What can I do to remove the warring and the error? 
Thank you.

the source code can be found here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55691/Neural-Network-Learning-by-the-Levenberg-Marquardt?msg=5211101#xx5211101xx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Blogs/55691/accord-levenberg-source.zip

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5):
>   warning MSB3268: The primary reference
>   "C:\Users...\accord-levenberg-source\Sources\Accord.Neuro\bin\Debug\Accord.Neuro.dll";
>   could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the
>   framework assembly ";System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"; which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ";.NETFramework,Version=v2.0";. To
>   resolve this problem, either remove the reference
>   "C:\Users..\accord-levenberg-source\Sources\Accord.Neuro\bin\Debug\Accord.Neuro.dll";
>   or retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   ";System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";.

2-

> C:\Users...\accord-levenberg-source\Samples\Neuro\Levenberg\XORProblem\MainForm.cs(23,7,23,13):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Accord' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have one project targeting .NET 2.0 that is referencing another project targeting .NET 3.5.  This is not allowed.  You need to change the first project to use .NET 3.5 or newer.

Comment: ok thanks, but how to do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in answer only

1.

> To resolve this problem, either remove the reference
>   "C:\Users..\accord-levenberg-source\Sources\Accord.Neuro\bin\Debug\Accord.Neuro.dll";
>   or retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   ";System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";.

2. Try to add reference, using Add Reference.. in the Project using Visual studio.

Comment: I removed the file and tried to add reference but still is same.